# How to stop both inline and default error messages on events registration form?

Tags: civievent, error

I've got an event form that is printing out error messages twice.

[image]

One is 'inline images

```
<input class="required crm-form-radio error crm-inline-error alert-danger" value="3" type="radio" id="CIVICRM_QFID_3_gender_id" name="gender_id">
<label for="CIVICRM_QFID_3_gender_id">Other</label>
<label id="gender_id-error" class="crm-inline-error alert-danger" for="gender_id">Required<label for="CIVICRM_QFID_3_gender_id">Other</label></label>
```

Comment: What are your CRM and CMS versions? I could not reproduce this issue on Civi 5.37.1 & Drupal 8. I have created an event form with required fields. Then submitted the form without filling it. The client side validation printed the 'This field is required.' error messages for me only once / required field.

Comment: Doesn't seem to happen with d8.  D7.82and 5.38.0. There is a javascript file that seems to be adding the second log I10n.js.tpl - web/sites/all/modules/civicrm/templates/CRM/common/l10n.js.tpl